# Appending two excel files into one dataframe

Tags: r, excel, append

I am trying to append two excel files from `Excel` into `R`.

I am using the following the code to do so:

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
library(rio) #this is for the excel appending
library("dplyr") #this is required for filtering and selecting
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

path1 <- "A:/Users/Desktop/Test1.xlsx"
path2 <- "A:/Users/Desktop/Test2.xlsx"


dat = bind_rows(path1,path2)
```

**Output**

```
> dat = bind_rows(path1,path2)
Error: Argument 1 must have names.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred
```

I appreciate that this is more for combining rows together, but can someone help me with combining difference workbooks into one dataframe in `R Studio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind_rows()` works with data frames AFTER they have been loaded into the R environment. Here are you merely trying to "bind" 2 strings of characters together, hence the error. First you need to import the data from Excel, which you could do with something like:

```
test_df1 <- readxl::read_xlsx(path1)
test_df2 <- readxl::read_xlsx(path2)
```

and then you should be able to run:

```
test_df <- bind_rows(test_df1, test_df2)
```

A quicker way would be to iterate the process using the `map` function from `purrr`:

```
test_df <- map_df(c(path1, path2), readxl::read_xlsx)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to append ***one under the other***, meaning that both excels have the same columns, I would

1. select the rows I wanted from the first excel and create a dataframe
2. select the rows from the second excel and create a second dataframe
3. append them with `rbind()`.

On the other hand if you want to ***append the one next to another***, I would choose the columns needed from first and second excel into two dataframes respectively and then I would go with `cbind()`